# Algorithm for DNA splitting

Tags: c, algorithm, statistics

I wanted to find out the effect of temperature and binding energy on the splitting of the DNA.
I have used a simple 1 dimensional walk to describe the position of the DNA polymers. I have set the initial condition such that they are overlapping. The initial position is a self avoiding and unidirectional random walk. The polymers have 128 monomers each whose positions are given by the array a[0-127] and b[0-127]. There is an energy E (which I have taken to -1) associated with two monomers being at the same position. No energy in all other separation distance.
Now I have used the Metropolis algorithm to bring the polymers to equilibrium.
I have randomly selected a monomer (out of the 256) and flipped it. Flipping has been defined as

> a[i] = a[i+1] + a[i-1] + a[1]

It would be 'b' instead of 'a' in case of the second polymer.
Of course if the final polymer is selected the flip would be defined by

> a[127] = 2*a[126] + a[127]

It should be noted that due to a flip the position would change be either 2,0 or -2.

Now the metropolis algorithm states that a flip would always be allowed if there is no energy change due to the flip (for example if an already separated monomer goes even further or if a separated monomer comes closer but not completely together). 
A flip will also always be allowed when the energy change is negative ie when after flipping two monomers come together.
When there is a positive energy change ie when initially two monomers are together but after the flip they separate then the flip is accepted with the probability of

> powf(M_E, (E/T))

T is also taken as 1 for the moment.

This algorithm is iterated many times until an equilibrium has been reached with regards to the end separation distance ie b[127]-a[127].
To generate the random numbers, I have used a drand function which I have defined in my code. Since someone told me it is probably not a very good random number generator I also tried using a function ran2 which I have just copied onto the code without how it is working.

Anyway now my problem is the equilibrium distance is coming out to be much higher than what is should be. Ideally I was told that it should come out to be 0 or maybe 2 and 4 at maximum. More than that is very unlikely. But my code is very frequently giving values like 22, 30 and so on.
Could someone tell me what is wrong? Feel free to ask for further clarifications.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define IM1 2147483563
#define IM2 2147483399
#define AM (1.0/IM1)
#define IMM1 (IM1-1)
#define IA1 40014
#define IA2 40692
#define IQ1 53668
#define IQ2 52774
#define IR1 12211
#define IR2 3791
#define NTAB 32
#define NDIV (1+IMM1/NTAB)
#define EPS 1.2e-7
#define RNMX (1.0-EPS)


float drand()
{
    float f, r, randmax;
    r = rand();
    randmax = RAND_MAX;
    f = r/(randmax+1);
    return(f);
}

double ran2(long *idum)
{
    int j;
    long k;
    static long idum2=123456789;
    static long iy=0;
    static long iv[NTAB];
    double temp;

    if (*idum <= 0)           /* Initialize. */
    {
        if (-(*idum) < 1) *idum=1;  /*Be sure to prevent idum = 0. */
        else *idum = -(*idum);
        idum2=(*idum);
        for (j=NTAB+7; j>=0; j--) /* Load the shuffle table (after 8 warm-ups).*/
        {
            k=(*idum)/IQ1;
            *idum=IA1*(*idum-k*IQ1)-k*IR1;
            if (*idum < 0) *idum += IM1;
            if (j < NTAB) iv[j] = *idum;
        }
        iy=iv[0];
    }
    k=(*idum)/IQ1; /* Start here when not initializing.*/
    *idum=IA1*(*idum-k*IQ1)-k*IR1; /* Compute idum=(IA1*idum) % IM1 without
                                   overflows by Schrage's method. */
    if (*idum < 0) *idum += IM1;
    k=idum2/IQ2;
    idum2=IA2*(idum2-k*IQ2)-k*IR2; /* Compute idum2=(IA2*idum) % IM2 likewise. */
    if (idum2 < 0) idum2 += IM2;
    j=iy/NDIV;                    /* Will be in the range 0..NTAB-1. */
    iy=iv[j]-idum2;               /* Here idum is shuffled, idum and idum2 are
                                  combined to generate output. */
    iv[j] = *idum;
    if (iy < 1) iy += IMM1;
    if ((temp=AM*iy) > RNMX)
        return RNMX;               /* Because users don't expect endpoint values. */
    else return temp;
}


int main()
{
    int a[128],b[128]; /*array defining position of polymer*/
    long int i, j;          /* integers defined for iteration purposes*/
    int r;             /* The rth random monomer of the polymer while conducting the MC algorithm*/
    int x;             /* The new position of the monomer if it overcomes the probability*/
    float E = -1;       /* Energy associated with overlapping monomers*/
    float T = 1;       /* Temperature*/
    int t;              /*separation between final monomers*/
    long idum = time(NULL);
    srand (time(NULL)); /*set seed for the random number*/
    a[0]=0;
    b[0]=0;
    for (i=1; i<128; i++) /*Defining a random but overlapping initial position for the strands*/
    {
        if (ran2(&idum)<0.5)
        {
            a[i]=a[i-1]+1;
            b[i]=a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            a[i]=b[i]=a[i-1]-1;
            b[i]=a[i];
        }
    }

    /* Following is the metropolis algorithm*/
    for (j=1; j<1000000; j=j+1)
    {
        r = floor(ran2(&idum)*128);
        if (ran2(&idum)<0.5)
        {
            if (r<=126)
            {
                x=a[r+1]+a[r-1]-a[r];
                if (x==b[r])
                {
                    a[r]=x;
                }
                else if (x==b[r]-2)
                {
                    if (ran2(&idum)<powf(M_E,(E/T)))
                    {
                        a[r]=x;
                    }
                }
                else if (x<b[r]-2)
                {
                    a[r]=x;
                }
            }
            else if (r==127)
            {
                x=2*a[126]-a[127];
                if (x==b[127])
                {
                    a[127]=x;
                }
                else if (x==b[127]-2)
                {
                    if (ran2(&idum)<powf(M_E,(E/T)))
                    {
                        a[127]=x;
                    }
                }
                else if (x<b[127]-2)
                {
                    a[127]=x;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (r<=126)
            {
                x=b[r+1]+b[r-1]-b[r];
                if (x==a[r])
                {
                    b[r]=x;
                }
                else if (x==a[r]+2)
                {
                    if (ran2(&idum)<powf(M_E,(E/T)))
                    {
                        b[r]=x;
                    }
                }
                else if (x>a[r]+2)
                {
                    b[r]=x;
                }
            }
            else if (r==127)
            {
                x=2*b[126]-b[127];
                if (x==a[127])
                {
                    b[127]=x;
                }
                else if (x==a[127]+2)
                {
                    if (ran2(&idum)<powf(M_E,(E/T)))
                    {
                        b[127]=x;
                    }
                }
                else if (x>a[127]+2)
                {
                    b[127]=x;
                }
            }
        }
        t = b[127]-a[127];
        if (j%(25600)==0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", t);
        }
    }
    printf("%f\n", powf(M_E,(E/T)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you're asking us to analyze your algorithm, and then find the problem in it? I think this would be too much to ask, because your algorithm is quite extensive. You're code looks very nice/clean though; well done! Can't you zoom in, or cut the processing in parts and check intermediate results?

Comment: Yes. I did realise that the code is quite long but I tried my best to find a problem before I posted it here.

Comment: I did try to isolate certain parts so I could find a problem. There doesn't seem to be any problem with the random number generators. Nor with the initial setting up of the polymers. The problem has to be within the metropolis algorithm. The results come out much more sensible when the number of iterations are lower. But as we increase the iterations the values get weirder and weirder despite the fact that they should reach equilibrium at a certain point and just stay there after subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I have realised what error I had been making.
First there is a redundant b[i]=a[i].
Probably not an error but a I am sure a bad coding habit.
Second. I friend pointed out that my algorithm called the value of r=0 as and my code uses a[r-1] which would then give out random numbers. I actually have to make sure that r doesn't take up the value of 0 since the first monomers of both polymers are kept fixed at 0.

The final and most major problem, are in the statements

```
else if (x==a[127]+2)
            {
                if (ran2(&idum)<powf(M_E,(E/T)))
                {
                    b[127]=x;
                }
            }
```

and

```
else if (x==b[r]-2)
            {
                if (ran2(&idum)<powf(M_E,(E/T)))
                {
                    a[r]=x;
                }
```

and also where r = 127 but you get the point.
Actually I thought that the monomer could be flipping only from a position where it is next to the other polymer ie a[r] = b[r] to the new position x. But after many iterations there would also be the case where a[r]+4=b[r] and it goes to a new position x where x==b[r]-2.
And this flip would always be accepted and not with a certain less than 1 probability.
So the new lines of the code should be

```
else if (x==b[r]-2)
            {
                if (a[r]==b[r])
                {
                    if (drand()<powf(M_E,(E/T)))
                {
                    a[r]=x;
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    a[r]=x;
                }
            }
```

And similarly for the other 3 cases. This takes care of both the possibilities. The code is working fine now.
Thanks to all those who took pain in going through such a long question.